# How do I compile and install the source code on OpenShift?

Tags: compilation, installation, makefile, openshift, openshift-cartridge

I'm trying to install 'whois' on OpenShift online, 
I can't install with yum due to the permissions

```
\> yum install whois
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
CRITICAL:yum.main:

Error: rpmdb open failed
```

I don't know any alternative ways to install a package, so considering to compile source code.

make is available.

```
\> make -version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
```

so how can I compile source code over SSH on OpenShift?
thank you so much!

Edit:
I can `make` the package but cant `install` the package.

Update:
Adds environment variables and related data.

`$PATH`

```
[app-domain.rhcloud.com whois-5.2.7]\> echo $PATH
/var/lib/openshift/{{ directory_hash }}/python//virtenv/bin:/var/lib/openshift/{{ directory_hash }}/python//bin:/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

`install`

```
[app-domain.rhcloud.com whois-5.2.7]\> which install
/var/lib/openshift/{{ directory_hash }}/python/bin/install
```

Error message during `make install`

```
[app-domain.rhcloud.com whois-5.2.7]\> make install BASEDIR=./destdir/
install -d ./destdir//usr/bin/
/var/lib/openshift/{{ directory_hash }}/python//bin/install: line 10: version: unbound variable
make: *** [install-whois] Error 1
```

Error message during `make /path/to/install`

```
[app-domain.rhcloud.com whois-5.2.7]\> make /var/lib/openshift/{{ directory_hash }}/python/bin/install BASEDIR=./destdir/
make: Nothing to be done for `/var/lib/openshift/{{ directory_hash }}/python/bin/install'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**
Your posted environment `$PATH` variable suggests that system's `install` command is probably overtaken by `python`'s `install` command. That is why the make command fails, when trying to install binaries.

You have two solutions.

- temporarily remove the `python` path from the `$PATH` variable. It will be restored to original value when you log in to OpenShift next time:

  `export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin`
- edit `Makefile` and `po/Makefile` files and set fixed path to `install` command to `/usr/bin/install`. The line in both `Makefile`s:

  `INSTALL = install`

  should read:

  `INSTALL = /usr/bin/install`

---

To solve permission issues while installing to `/usr` you will have to install `whois` to custom dir. This example installs it to `destdir` subdirectory.

```
$ wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/w/whois/whois_5.2.7.tar.xz
$ tar xf whois_5.2.7.tar.xz
$ cd whois-5.2.7/
$ mkdir destdir
$ make
$ make install BASEDIR=./destdir/
$ ./destdir/usr/bin/whois --version
Version 5.2.7.

Report bugs to <md+whois@linux.it>.
```

Comment: same bug, `unbound variable`! have tried changing the `install` to its absolute path, still not working!

Comment: Could you post somewhere the whole output of `make install` including the error message?

Comment: can i access the installed package with `whois` from the terminal?

Comment: The `whois` binary is installed to `./destdir/usr/bin/whois`. You can run it from terminal specifying full path to the binary. You may also add the path to your `$PATH` variable and run it as `whois` without specifying the path. See how I run it in my answer.

Comment: I used to execute the made package (with `make`) the same way! so there ain't a way to get it executed with typing just `whois`? what is the point of the installation if it has to run the package just like executing made package?

Comment: `whois` is a dependency and I just want it to be executed with whois, can you look into this?

Comment: You could set path to your `whois` binary in a start hook: `$app/.openshift/action_hooks/start`. Read https://forums.openshift.com/permanently-add-to-path

Comment: One more help, can you just update what the action_hook for setting up the path for the current installation path? just to make sure it work. thanks.

Comment: Add `PATH=/path_to_whois_binary:$PATH` line to `$app/.openshift/action_hooks/start` file. However note that it will not work in your ssh session. The path will be available to you app. If you have more questions I suggest you ask new question describing you application and you goals

Answer (score 0):

First you should fetch the source code of 'whois':

```
wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/w/whois/whois_5.2.7.tar.xz
```

Then it is necessary to extract it:

```
tar -xf whois_5.2.7.tar.xz
```

Now you have a directory with the source code, so the last step is to compile it with 'make'.

I think all that can be done through SSH on OpenShift.

Comment: I've done all till make, can run the package on shell but can't install. it says, `unbound variable`

Comment: anyway i can install the package after make?

Comment: It's been a while since I've manually compiled a application, but isn't the process to do "make install" after you "make" it? I think that's the step you're missing. Correct me if I'm completely wrong.

Comment: @Zhinkk thats what the exact process is, but `install` command throws `unbound variable`